# ActionScript 3 TextArea htmlText styling using <span> tag

Tags: css, apache-flex, actionscript-3, textarea, htmltext

According to this [webpage](http://blog.flexcommunity.net/?p=38), the htmlText property in TextArea can handle CSS text style if using span tag. I want to format multiple tags in my code. Something like:

```
var tags:TextArea = new TextArea(); 
tags.htmlText = "<span style='color: rgb(165, 150, -90); 
  font-size: 0.955882610016677em'>street</span>,
  <span style='color: rgb(168, 143, -59); font-size: 0.98076913067067em'>
  motor</span>";
```

It only gives me plain text. I was wondering if it is supported in the htmlText property and how do I get around this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `htmlText` supports only a limited set of [tags and styles](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText). Specifically, span supports only a `class` attribute which should be the name of a class specified in a [`StyleSheet`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html) object.

You can use the `font` tag in this particular case. But remember that color supports only hexadecimal `#ffffff` values and `size` supports only absolute pixel size and relative (+2, -1 etc) size values.

```
tags.htmlText = "<font color="#a89433" size="10">street</font>,
  <font color="#b37620" size="11">motor</font>";
```

Comment: I was working on that problem for 5 hours and couldn't figure it out. Thank you SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/theflashbum/fcss/

Not directly answering your question, but you should check out this project. CSS support in AS3 is awful, F*CSS mitigates some of that pain.

Comment: It is not a direct answer but thank you for this. I'll check it out.